# Spring boot, JDBC Не работает откат изменений в аннотированном @Transactional методе

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, transaction

Пишу REST сервис из контроллера вызывается Сервис 
В методе сервиса помеченого @Transactional проиходят такие действия:
1.вызывается метод объекта DAO для получения контента
2. после идет проверка условия, 
3.потом делается апдейт в базу данных (markAnsweredQuestion())
4. далее через метод объекта DAO делается запрос на получение контента (getPositiveMessage() в этом месте происходит ошибка).
 Если последний пункт не выполняется, все равно update в базу происходит, а должен произойти откат изменений, не могу понять почему не проиходит отката изменений.
QuestionService.class

```
@Service
public class QuestionService implements IContentService {

/** Компонент для работы с базой данных */
private QuestionDao questionDao;

private Log log;

/** Конструктор класса */
public QuestionService(QuestionDao questionDao, Log log) {
    this.questionDao = questionDao;
    this.log = log;
}

/**
 * Проверка ответа на вопрос
 * @param contentType тип контента
 * @param questionNum номер ответа
 * @param answer      номер ответа
 * @return Контент позитивного сообщения
 * @throws InvalidAnswerException Ошибка что ответ дан не верно
 */
@Transactional(rollbackFor = CoreException.class)
public Content checkAnswer(String contentType, int questionNum, Answer answer) throws SQLException, InvalidAnswerException {
    Content question = questionDao.getContent(ContentType.QUESTION, questionNum);
    boolean isCorrect = checkCurrentAnswer(question, answer);
    if (!isCorrect) {
        InvalidAnswerException exception = new InvalidAnswerException(questionNum, "Не правильно, Попробуй еще раз, малышка");
        log.error("Неверный ответ.", exception);
        throw exception;
    }
    questionDao.markAnsweredQuestion(questionNum);
    return questionDao.getPositiveMessage(answer.getAnswer());
}

/**
 * Сравнивает id ответа на вопрос и id корректного ответа
 * @param questionContent контент вопроса
 * @param answer          ответ пользователя
 * @return true если ответ верный, false если неверный
 */
private boolean checkCurrentAnswer(Content questionContent, Answer answer) {
    Question question = (Question) questionContent.getContent();
    return question.getCurrentAnswer() == answer.getAnswer();
}
```

QuesttionDao.class

```
@Component
public class QuestionDao {

/**
 * Конструктор класса
 * @param log Логгер
 */
public QuestionDao(Log log) {
    this.log = log;
}

/**
 * Инициализация подключения к базе данных
 * @throws SQLException            Ошибки работы с базой данных
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException  Ошибка драйвера h2.Driver
 */
@PostConstruct
public void initConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATA_BASE_URL, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
    log.warn("Connected: " + connection.getCatalog());
}

/**
 * Проверяется правильностть ответа на вопрос
 * @param answerNum   номер ответа
 * @return Сообщение пользователю
 * @throws SQLException Ошибка работы с базой данных
 * @throws InvalidAnswerException Ошибка, что был дан неправилльный ответ
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Content getPositiveMessage(int answerNum) throws SQLException {
    Content content = new Content();
    PreparedStatement prstmt = connection.prepareStatement(GET_POSITIVE_MESSAGE_QUERY);
    prstmt.setInt(1, answerNum);
    ResultSet messageResult = prstmt.executeQuery();
    if (messageResult.next()) {
        Message message = buildMessage(messageResult);
        content.setContent(message);
        return content;
    }
    throw new CoreException("Ошибкка работы с базой данных");
}

public void markAnsweredQuestion(int questionId) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement prstmt = connection.prepareStatement(MARK_ANSWERED_QUESTION);
    prstmt.setInt(1, questionId);
    prstmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class QuestionServiceApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(QuestionServiceApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

Comment: `InvalidAnswerException` - наследник `CoreException`?

Comment: Нет, но они все наследники exception

Comment: Тогда почему вы ждёте, что при выбросе `InvalidAnswerException` будет откат транзакции? Вы же явно указали в аннотации, что откат нужно проводить только при выбросе `CoreException`.

Comment: мне нужно, сделать откат транзакции, когда в методе `questionDao.getPositiveMessage(answer.getAnswer())` выбросится SqlException. Я попробовал поменять `@Transactional(rollbackFor = SQLException.class)` но не помогло.

Comment: Попробуйте `rollbackFor` вообще убрать.

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло, такое чувство, что транзакция вообще не создается

Comment: По-моему, если нужно использовать спринговое управление транзакциями, то и для работы с БД нужно использовать инфраструктуру спринга, а у вас же соединение создается вручную, то и управлять транзакциями нужно вручную.

Comment: @RuslanP. Вы скорее всего правы, я сделал упраавление транзакцией вручную, и она работает. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, Вы вызываете метод checkAnswer прямо внутри QuestionService. В таком случае аннотация не сработает, т.к. метод вызовется напрямую, прокси не будет создан.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, я вызываю этот метод в контроллере `questionService.checkAnswer(); `

Comment: Тогда это не ваш случай! Если внутри QuestionService будет метод, который вызовет checkAnswer(), то в таком случае аннотация не сработает

Comment: Ну тогда да, там метод не будет работатть через прокси